# Implanting an extra variable to count the number of times an "unique" item is found in an array.

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sorting

I've got a sub representing a commandbutton of my userform, this userform has the perpose of listing (in a listbox) all unique items found in a column of a two-dimensional array. At frst I would like to implant an extra variable to hold and thus represent the number of times the unique item appears in the array. Secondly I would like the (Unique) items listed as:

*Unique item 1* (*number of appearances*).

Example 1 (23)

Example 2 (39)

Example 3 (101)

Example 4 (9)

...

Example n (#)

Here is the code, can some body help me out?

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dictUnq As Object
Dim UnqList() As String
Dim aData As Variant
Dim vData As Variant
Dim pData As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim PrintString1() As String
i = 1

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set dictUnq = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

With ws.Range("G2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
    If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        aData(1, 1) = .Value
    Else
        aData = .Value
    End If
End With

SBI_Omschrijving.ListBox1.Clear

For Each vData In aData
    If Len(vData) > 0 Then
        If Not dictUnq.exists(vData) Then dictUnq.Add vData, vData
    End If
Next vData

Debug.Print dictUnq(vData)

SBI_Omschrijving.ListBox1.List = dictUnq.keys
MsgBox "Unique findings:  " & dictUnq.Count


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Comment: loop the array and add to a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store the count? This demonstrates the principle. Note in your example I think you may only be adding one column G so I don't know of you intended more?

```
Sub test()

Dim myArray()

myArray = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

Dim dict As Object

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1) 'Depending on column of interest. Loop that

    If Not dict.Exists(myArray(i, 1)) Then
        dict.Add myArray(i, 1), 1
    Else
       dict(myArray(i, 1)) = dict(myArray(i, 1)) + 1
    End If

Next i

Dim key As Variant

For Each key In dict.keys
    Debug.Print key & "(" & dict(key) & ")"
Next key

End Sub
```

Your example might be something like (can't test dictionary on a mac I'm afraid so coding in my head)

```
Sub test()

    Dim aData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

   If lastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub

    Set targetRange = ws.Range("G2:G" & lastRow)

    If targetRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        aData(1, 1) = targetRange.Value
   Else
       aData = targetRange.Value2
   End If

    Dim dictUnq As Object

    Set dictUnq = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1) 'Depending on column of interest. Loop that

        If Not dictUnq.Exists(aData(i, 1)) Then
            dictUnq.Add aData(i, 1), 1
        Else
           dictUnq(aData(i, 1)) = dictUnq(aData(i, 1)) + 1
        End If

    Next i

    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In dictUnq.keys
        Debug.Print key & "(" & dictUnq(key) & ")"
    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @QHarr, Thanks for helping, but when I run the code, I get the following msg: 

"Run-time error'429':

ActiveX component can't create object"

Any idea how to prevent this error?

Comment: Thanks for your Help @Qharr

Answer (score 1):

another possibility

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Dim dictUnq As Object
    Set dictUnq = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim cell As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
        For Each cell In .Range("G2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
            dictUnq(cell.Value) = dictUnq(cell.Value) + 1
        Next
    End With

    If dictUnq.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim key As Variant
    With SBI_Omschrijving.ListBox1
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 2
        For Each key In dictUnq.keys
            .AddItem key
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = dictUnq(key)
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox "Unique findings:  " & dictUnq.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a posibility to print the data as listed in the list in an new sheet so i can print them on paper?